Past continuous with repeated actions
During my study I learned that we use past continuous when we want to show or emphasize duration. For instance:
1 "When he was a kid he was learning all the time"
What if I change something here
2 "When he was a kid, every Saturday, he was learning all the time"
The reason why I'm unsure about my 2 version is because 1 was vague not specific and 2 points out every Saturday so if it was repeated every Saturday then past simple seems to be a better choice but on the other hand I want to emphasize the duration of learning on Saturdays. Is my 2 example correct?

Not even your sentence 1 sounds natural. An example where the continuous does work is When he was a kid he was always getting into trouble. The verb learn just doesn’t sound right in this kind of habitual usage. That’s simply how English works. As has been suggested to you in others of your questions, just use English; one can’t develop high proficiency by asking series of particular questions about how to use the language. Simply use it, both as a producer and a consumer. And when you read and listen, be attentive for nuance.

(1) seems OK to me if it means 'he was constantly learning new things, both in school and in everyday life'. Adding every Saturday makes nonsense of this, since children are not usually at school on Saturdays - and 'on Saturdays' isn't 'all the time'.
